# RewriteRule creating 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^directory/(.*)$ directory/index.php?id=$1
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

When the URL `www.example.com/directory/10` is visited, the page `www.example.com/directory/?id=10` is displayed on the browser without altering the appearance of the URL.

The above code creates a 500 Internal server error though.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: A 500 error generally means an error has been logged somewhere. Find your Apache and PHP error logs, and see what the actual error is.

Comment: The 500 error delivered to the browser should have informed you that the full error message would be in the server logs. Read them.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your code is guaranteed to generate 500 internal server error because it is causing infinite looping. Reason is that your matching URI pattern is: `^directory/(.*)$`

Which matches your URLs before and after rewrites. And once it reaches max allowed internal rewrite limit Apache throws 500 internal server error and bails out.

Change your code to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^directory/(.*)$ directory/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Above code has an extra `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` that will make sure to disallow subsequent execution of RewriteRule after first time since `/directory/index.php` will be a valid file.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I didn't realize that my rewrite rule also was referencing itself. Adding the rewrite condition fixed the issue. Something obvious but easy to overlook.

Comment: Had same problem. I thought it is [OR] operand, took too much time and finally read your answer and found the loop. you are my angel. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

I have got the same issue and found that "rewrite" module is not yet enabled in my case. So I need to enable it and then restart apache server:

- Enable "rewrite" module: **sudo a2enmod rewrite**
- Then restart apache server: **sudo service apache2 restart**

Hope this will help anyone.

Answer (score 3):

You should try adding a forward slash to the front:

```
RewriteRule ^/directory/(.*)$ directory/index.php?id=$1
```

I've been caught out with that before.

Alternatively use the RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel to debug, and look at the Apache error and access logs for further info:

```
RewriteLogLevel 3
RewriteLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/rewrite.log
```

That will leave a log file in your apache log directory. In my case that is `/var/log/apache`

Comment: Well that's sorted the server error, but now I get `The requested URL /directory/10 was not found on this server.` Any ideas?

Comment: Well, now it sounds like the Rewrite isn't matching.

Comment: Add a RewriteLog in your vhost (the are not valid in .htaccess) to point to the log file you wang to write to. I've edited my answer with an example.

Comment: Your solution cannot work because RewriteRule doesn't match leading slash in .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CodeIgniter and is in error problems 500. Follow the solution.

So to delete the segment "index.php" of URLs in CodeIgniter, you need to do 2 things. The first is to edit the `/system/application/config/config.php` file, changing the value of index_page policy to empty:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

The second step is to create a file `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And that's it! From now on, the URLs of your site/system made with CodeIgniter will no longer have the thread (called "annoying" by some) "index.php".

Answer (score 0):

Another day searching for a strange error on Apache.
Working on my Docker Apache 2.4.48 alpine container. But not in production.

Here is the difference (just a dot):

Not working on hosting provider

```
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ ./public/index.php?route=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Working on hosting provider

```
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ /public/index.php?route=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just uncomment #LoadModule rewrite_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so

Because by default it was disabled/commented

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. I believe it would greatly help everyone if you could explain why and how this answer solves the OP's problem!

Comment: Because by default it was disabled/commented