# Create custom folder in wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hi i have a wordpress site and i want to create a custom folder in the root directory which will be independant from the wordpress. What rewrite rule i have to use in order to access that folder?
I have put

```
RewriteRule ^clients? /clients/index.php [L]
```

Current htaccess file

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^clients? /clients/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

When i access that folder i get an internal server error 500

Answer (score 0):

You must have an infinite rewrite loop, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17108691/3563439). Try this:

```
...
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^clients? /clients/index.php [L]
...
```

For perfection, you might want to add the `QSA` and `NC`flags as well.

Comment: Now i get an error 404 page in my wordpress as i am trying to visit a page in my wordpress site..

Answer (score 0):

Even if this was a very old question. I wanted to answer it for those who are noobs like me when it comes to .htaccess rules.

This should be the rule that you were looking for your situation and the place that you put it in .htaccess file must be right so there is no need to change its place.

`RewriteRule ^clients/(.*) clients/index.php [L]`