# RewriteCond/RewriteRule work in test, but not on (shared) hosting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This seems like it should be a simple directive to serve images from a different path on a shared server:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)/(.*)\.(jpe?g|png)$ images/large/$1/$2_LRG.$3 [E=VAR1:$1,E=VAR2:$2,E=VAR3:$3,L,NC]
```

When [testing the RewriteRule](http://example.com/images/2013items/painted-steel-cable-rail.JPG) it works as expected:

Request: `http://example.com/images/2013items/painted-steel-cable-rail.JPG`

Result: `http://example.com/images/large/2013items/painted-steel-cable-rail_LRG.JPG`

But the browser is simply being server the originally requested file, as if there's no match.

It's a shared hosting account and I have tried to set logging, which doesn't seem to work so far.

```
LogLevel 3
RewriteLog /home/myuseraccount/public_html/rewrite.log
```

Additionally there are some `mod_headers` and `mod_expires` configurations, but I don't imagine they would be expected to effect the `mod_rewrite` behavior.

Apologies for increasing the count of nearly 28,000 `mod_rewrite` questions, but I'd be grateful for any further insights into troubleshooting this.

Comment: Well, it seems you have access to quite a lot of things on that service, which is very uncommon on a shared hosting... Maybe you can even access the http servers error log file? Because that is where you can read what the issue is...

Comment: Which `originally requested file`. Because you only rewrite files that do not exist. Or try without `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: Yes. webhostingbuzz are the hosts and i like them a lot. The only errors i have direct access to are via the cpanel and they don't contain anything relevant (not much at all). Am in touch with their tech support via email...

Comment: @Croises without the `RewriteCond` line I was getting a 500 error so based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/17108691/2223106 added it.

Comment: I think there is some infinite looping going on, but am not sure how to fix it. Now am getting `http://www.examle.com/images/large/large/large/large/large/large/large/large/large/large/large/large/large/large/large/large/large/large/large/large/large/2013items/painted-steel-cable-rail_LRG_LRG_LRG_LRG_LRG_LRG_LRG_LRG_LRG_LRG_LRG_LRG_LRG_LRG_LRG_LRG_LRG_LRG_LRG_LRG_LRG.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/large/
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)/(.*)\.(jpe?g|png)$ images/large/$1/$2_LRG.$3 [E=VAR1:$1,E=VAR2:$2,E=VAR3:$3,L,NC]
```

Because if you test -f you do not use the rule. And without, you call it again and again for the corrected url which also corresponds to the rule.

Or you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png)$ images/large/$1/$2_LRG.$3 [E=VAR1:$1,E=VAR2:$2,E=VAR3:$3,L,NC]
```

Comment: What if I wanted it to _only_ redirect _if_ the `large` image exists?

Comment: You can test with `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/large/$1/$2_LRG.$3 -f` before line `RewriteRule ^images....`