# htaccess won't load index until i add index

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to remove folder from the URL and I did that, but the problem is when i visit domain.com it shows error 500, but if i add domain.com/index.php it will work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /insta/member/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+insta/member/pages/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^insta/member/pages)^(.*)$ /insta/member/pages/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this set of rules, looks like the requests are considered to always be files and if the request file name is not a file, then it adds `.php` to it. It is not always the case though. In [apache 2.2 mode_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

> REQUEST_FILENAME : The full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the request, if this has already been determined by the server at the time REQUEST_FILENAME is referenced. Otherwise, such as when used in virtual host context, the same value as REQUEST_URI

Therefore, the REQUEST_FILENAME may be resolved to files, folders or directories 
(this may vary in other web services or other apache versions). In case of files the rules work otherwise it fails. For example `//domain.com` will be resolved to the document root. But `//domain.com/index.php` will be resolved to the index.php file in the document root. To avoid these kind of confusions, all three possibilities should be considered, generally speaking. Also the `REQUEST_FILENAME` may be a file by itself without .php like `//domain.com/my_styles.css`. In that case the rules fail too.
Following set of rules should work

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /insta/member/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
    RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+insta/member/pages/([^\s]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule (?!^insta/member/pages)^(.*)$ /insta/member/pages/$1 [L,NC]
```

**Edit:**
Explanation for first set of rules is that it is checking if the resolved filename part of the request is not a directory, link or file and "filename.php" is a file and it is not ending with forward slash then add .php to the request.

**Answering to the question in comment about pretty url:**

To achieve pretty url you need to know the application routing. For removing a GET parameter from query string like `?checking=value` rule should be like following

```
RewriteRule (.*)/checking/(.*)$ $1?checking=$2 [L]
```

It will be like following to combine with the above rules

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /insta/member/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule (.*)/checking/(.*)$ $1\.php?checking=$2 [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [QSA,L]
```

Then `$_GET` values for following examples would be

```
    http://localhost/insta/member/test
    array (size=0)
      empty

    http://localhost/insta/member/test?checking=value
    array (size=1)
      'checking' => string 'value' (length=5)       

    http://localhost/insta/member/test/checking/value
    array (size=1)
      'checking' => string 'value' (length=5)

    http://localhost/insta/member/test/checking/value?second=2
    array (size=2)
      'checking' => string 'value' (length=5)
      'second' => string '2' (length=1)
```

Finally, here is the specific rule for `check/ig/value` to `check?ig=value` going to `check.php?ig=value`

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ $1.\php?$2=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Sample output for `GET`

```
    http://localhost/insta/member/check/ig/value
    array (size=1)
      'ig' => string 'value' (length=5)
```

Comment: Its not working like that. Internal error on every page.

Comment: Did you copy and past the code from this post? The code may have illegal character in this post.

Comment: Sorry body. My bad! Updated the response.

Comment: Now its working, thank you. I have one more question.. how to remove from GET "check?ig=value" and get like this
check/ig/value

Comment: Added to the answer!

Comment: Oh, you are awesome man, congratz :) Also, i have a little problem now with mod rewrite, i must add insta/member/index if i want to load my index page, when i visit insta/member it gives me error 500.

Comment: It should not. I don't see any problem here and it works for me. May be you have other rules!

Comment: [FAQ: What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I did it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite my wheelhouse, but I'm pretty sure you need:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Found here:

http://www.htaccess-guide.com/directoryindex-uses/

EDIT: After some conversation this is probably not the problem, but rather an infinite loop described here: [RewriteRule creating 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107940/rewriterule-creating-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: This is working good when i delete everything in .htaccess, so it is problem with the code

Comment: @НиколаР.  I don't understand, this is code for .htaccess.  Here's a different reference recommending adding the same line: https://www.sitepoint.com/htaccess-for-all/

Comment: @НиколаР. I think I see my miscommunication.  I'm not suggesting you download a tool or anything.  "DirectoryIndex index.php" is, I believe, standard syntax for an .htaccess file, where 'index.php' is the name of the file you want to serve should the path not be specified any further.  Or maybe I'm failing to understand the problem.

Comment: I removed line by line, and when i remove last two lines its working

Comment: Ah, that helps bring it into focus.  I was thinking this .htaccess might be overriding settings from ones upstream, but your comment makes it seem like there's no way that's the case.

I believe I've stumbled on your answer anyway.  Looks like you're catching you're causing an infinite loop because your condition is catching your urls post-modification, modifying them, and sending them back through over and over.

I played with the regex a bit in Sublime and this passes the sniff test.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107940/rewriterule-creating-500-internal-server-error

Comment: Nevermind that doesn't make sense either.  Then it wouldn't work when you supplied /index.php, though it could still be related.  I thought I had this one and got over-excited.  I'll just shut up now.

Comment: Ah, thank you man for trying. I really think that the server is expecting something after domain.com/, like when I put index it will load, but without index it won't..

Comment: Well but then it wouldn't work when you cleared the RewriteRule.  I feel sure this looping thing is the culprit somehow... but I'm trying to figure out why the discrepancy.

Comment: In short lines, he is removing directory name from URL, domain.com/pages/instagram, so it would become domain.com/instagram, without pages dir, and thats why he is expecting some parameter..

Comment: That's not the behavior I'm getting here: http://htaccess.mwl.be/.  It's a little tricky without knowing the details of your typical requests.  My lead suspicion right now is that this isn't actually working when you include /index.php.  That it's failing and falling back on old behavior that is working.  Any way I'm able to meaningfully engage this code results in a loop of it adding /insta... to itself over and over.

Comment: Its fixed by adding just 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Comment: Cool I'm glad you got it fixed.  I don't get why the solution works, but you seem to.